# Accessing a Bitnami install on VM from outside devices

Tags: bitnami

I have an apache/php/mysql bitnami install running in a VM on a windows box.  I can enter the IP of the VM into my host machines browser and the site-in-progress comes up just fine.

However, I need to view the site in progress from another device/computer (mobile testing). How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late with this answer but I think it adds value...

Most VM software has what is commonly called a 'bridged' mode (it's actually called 'Bridged Networking' in VirtualBox - I don't recall what it's called in VMware). This in essence allows the VM to get it's own independent IP on the LAN (just like a 'real' PC).

The downside is that it's not as secure (because the VM is totally exposed to the network), but the upside is that it's much quicker and easier to set up because you don't need to muck around with port forwarding and there is no risk of posts conflicting with the host or other VMs.

For full details of networking options in VirtualBox see this page: http://www.turnkeylinux.org/docs/virtual-networking-explained

Answer (score 1):

I don't know bitnami but virtualization software usually allows you to do port forwarding.

I do use VirtualBox and here is a good post describing how to set it up properly.

[Virtualbox "port forward" from Guest to Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537751/virtualbox-port-forward-from-guest-to-host)

Comment: Ah. I will see what the equivalency for VMware is.  Thanks.

Comment: You can find how to install VMware Tools on top of a BitNami virtual machine at http://wiki.bitnami.com/Virtual_Appliances_Quick_Start_Guide#How_to_install_VMware_tools_on_BitNami_Virtual_Appliances.3f I hope it helps