# ActiveMq messaging between Windows and Linux apps using Virtualbox on same PC not working

Tags: linux, windows, jms, activemq-classic, virtualbox

We are using Active MQ to have applications message each other. We have applications running on both Windows and Linux. During development, the team uses their Windows PC with VirtualBox with a RHEL Linux image. We are trying to run the Active MQ broker on the Linux local VM. When we do, messages from Windows can't use it. If we run the broker on Windows, the windows applications can message each other, but not the Linux apps.

I have tried setting port-forwarding in VB for 61616 (though what should the guest port be?), but that doesn't seem to do it. I forwarded 8161 listed in jetty.xml and am able to connect my Windows browser to it.

The exception text I get in Windows is "Channel was inactive for too long". I tried setting maxInactivityDuration to 0 for both sides, but that hasn't done it.

Any ideas on how to get this set-up to work?

Answer (score 1):

I just found a post on VirtualBox port forwarding that helped me. (Yes, I had searched like mad yesterday before posting my question this morning :)
[Virtualbox "port forward" from Guest to Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537751/virtualbox-port-forward-from-guest-to-host)

I set port forwarding as described in the section "Network communication Host -> Guest" of the post. I then updated my activemq.xml file...

```
<transportConnectors>
    <transportConnector ... uri="[my VM guest IP which was 10.0.2.15]:61616..." ... />     
</transportConnectors>
```

I still had to set wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration in the uri string for transportConnector, otherwise I was getting "Channel was inactive for too long" right away. I don't know why. Anyway, this is way further than I was yesterday.