# Access NodePort service from another machine in the same network

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I installed minikube on my mac and created deployment and a service for my nodejs app. I tested that everything is working by getting the URL of my service using the following command:

```
minikube service my-nodejs-app --url
```

and then I run this URL in the browser and got results. The problem is when i tried to access the same URL from another machine inside the same network it didn't worked.

my `service.yml` file is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-nodejs-app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 1337 
    protocol: TCP
    name: app-server
  selector:
    app:  my-nodejs-app
```

I tried to use port forwarding to forward my pod port to my localhost and it works only on the same machine who host the cluster and when I try to access from another machine on the same network (via the IP address of the machine where the cluster deployed) I still get page not found.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `"port forward a service"`. Assuming:

- Your local machine IP: `166.6.6.6` (which hold minikube)
- Your minikube IP: `192.168.99.100` (check the real IP with command `$minikube ip`)
- The nodePort of your service 'my-nodejs-app': `31000` (check the real
  nodePort with command: `$kubectl get service`)

In order to access your service from remote, you can forward a port (like 31000, recommend the same port with nodePort) to your service through the following command in your local machine:

> ssh -i ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa docker@$(minikube ip) -L \*:31000:0.0.0.0:31000

Then you can access your service through URL: `http://166.6.6.6:31000`, which will be forwarded to your service URL `http://192.168.99.100:31000`

Thx: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/877

Answer (score 2):

Probably a bit late, but if anyone still having this issue-

1. Check the list of services and the one you want to expose if it is present

```
kubectl get svc -n {namespace_name}
```

2. Change the type to NodePort if it is of cluster IP type.

```
kubectl patch svc {service_name} -n {namespace_name} --type='json' -p '[{"op":"replace","path":"/spec/type","value":"NodePort"}]'
```

3. Expose the above Node Port available to your local machine now for other machines on same network:

```
service_port=$(minikube service {service_name} -n {namespace_name} --url | cut -d':' -f3)
ssh -i ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa docker@$(minikube ip) -NL \*:${service_port}:0.0.0.0:${service_port}
```

Now you can access the above service from other machines on same network by just hitting the link-
`{your_hostname}:{node_port}`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like reaching it from another machine compares to exposing a ssevice to the web.
In that case you need to look into spec/type:LoadBalancer (http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/load-balancer/)
That said, with minikube i'd stick to a single machine and development only tests

Comment: Thanks, but i am developing a mobile app and when i try to test the app on a real mobile device it is not possible because i cannot reach from my mobile device to the service. 
BTW - i find a way to do it by installing a reverse proxy (NGINX) that forward the request to my service but i wanted to know if there is a better way..

Comment: Have you looked into setting a service with a loadbalancer type ? Because this is the better way ( the kubernetes way) and that's what i meant above

Comment: In minikube you cannot use LoadBalancer the type of the service must be NodePort

Comment: Allright my bad; i guess you're at it with the nginx proxy

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly:

Your machine's IP: `192.168.1.4`
Your minikube IP: `192.168.99.100`
Accessing your service from a browser on your machine: `http://192.168.99.100:30080`

Now, let's say you're on another machine, say`192.168.1.5`, and you want to access this service.

The problem is that you need to map your machine's port to minikube's 30080 because minikube is a VM running on your machine (which cannot be accessed from outside your machine).

So you can try: [Virtualbox "port forward" from Guest to Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537751/virtualbox-port-forward-from-guest-to-host).

Another alternative is to forward a port from your localhost to a pod directly (not the k8s svc unfortunately) by using [kubectl port-forward](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/connecting-to-applications-port-forward/).

Comment: hi @iamnat, I tried kubectl port-forward (which seems to be the best solution) but its not working... I can try the "port forward" approach on the VirtualBox but don't you think it's better to install NGINX as reverse proxy? (this is my current working solution..)

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified nodePort in ports.
Add below configuration in port

nodePort: 30000

You can access your service at http://[IP address]:30000