# Unable to run mariaDB server on Debian based VM (Virtualbox)

Tags: debian, mariadb, virtualbox

When I try to run mysql in my debian based virtual machine I get the next output:

`user@host:~$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000):Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'(2)`

I also tried:

`user@host:~$ sudo mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000):Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'(2)`

Also:

`root@host:~$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000):Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'(2)`

I tried looking for the next configuration files in order to determine the socket:

`/etc/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
/var/lib/mysql/my.cnf`

None of these showed any socket configuration. MySQL is installed by default in this distribution.

`user@host:~$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.22-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2`

Comment: You need to forward the port see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10076989/5193536

Comment: And if you are getting a version of mariaDB then its not MySQL

Comment: Try `sudo service --status-all` to see if MySQL (or MariaDB) is running.